# SQL for weekly report

Tags: mysql, sql, report

I need to generate a weekly report for sales performance

---------------------------------------------------------
User    Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri    Sat    Sun    Total
---------------------------------------------------------
Naven    25    25     30     25    20    20     0         145
Ajay       15    35    20     25    20    20    0        135

I am using  classic asp

eg :

```
Select username , salesdate , salesamt 
from sales ...... 
group by username
```

Comment: If am not wrong you are looking for **conditional Aggregate** logic

Answer (score 0):

You can combine an aggregate function (e.g. SUM) with a CASE condition to get a report like you want.

For example:

```
SELECT USERNAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(SALESDATE)=0 THEN SALESAMT ELSE 0 END) AS MON,
SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(SALESDATE)=1 THEN SALESAMT ELSE 0 END) AS TUE

FROM SALES
GROUP BY USERNAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

create table test

```
create table `test` (
    `day` datetime ,
    `val` int (11),
    `user` varchar (768)
); 
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2012-01-01 00:00:00','465',NULL);
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2012-01-02 00:00:00','896',NULL);
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-26 11:37:07','678','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-26 11:37:07','324','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-27 11:37:14','74','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-25 11:37:14','65','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-25 11:37:14','35','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-02-01 11:35:59','12','Naveen');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-02-01 11:37:07','23','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-30 11:36:40','34','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-30 11:36:40','56','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-31 11:36:32','12','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-30 11:36:40','13','Ajay');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-28 11:36:46','14','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-02-01 11:37:07','10','Pankaj');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-02-01 11:37:07','10','Pankaj');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-27 11:37:14','20','Naven    ');
insert into `test` (`day`, `val`, `user`) values('2015-01-29 11:37:36','10','Naven    ');
```

Below the desire query

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DAY) AS sr ,DATE_FORMAT(DAY, '%a') DAY, SUM(val),USER, DAY FROM test
WHERE DAY >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+6 DAY
AND DAY < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
GROUP BY DAY,USER
ORDER BY sr;
```